# Analyzing a variable inside a method. JavaParser/ANTLR or something else?

Tags: java, parsing, variables, reflection, antlr

I am writing a java code analyzing snippet which will find out the use of variables in a method. (to be specific how many times a global class variable is read and written in a method). Can this be done using JavaParser? Would anyone have any other recommendations? Does any one know how class metrics are calculated? They probably deal with similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys. Both your answers lead me in a direction to solution to this problem using the AST implementation in JAVAPARSER. Here's a code snippet to help others

```
class CatchNameExpr extends VoidVisitorAdapter {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> variableLineNumMap;``
    ArrayList<String> variableList;
    boolean functionParsing = false;
    public CatchNameExpr(ArrayList<String> classVariables) {
        variableList=classVariables;
    }
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration method, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println(method.getName());
        System.out.println("---------------");
        variableLineNumMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        System.out.println();
        functionParsing = true;
        visit(method.getBody(),arg);
        // Analyze lines for variable usage. Add to list of vars after checking if its read or written or unknown.

        functionParsing = false;
    }

    public void visit(NameExpr n, Object arg) {

        if(!functionParsing)
            return;
        //TODO: check if this var was declared above it, as a local var to the func. if yes, return
        ArrayList<Integer> setOfLineNum;

        System.out.println(n.getBeginLine()+" NameExpr " + n.getName());

        if(!variableList.contains(n.getName()) || n.getName().length()==0)
            return;
        if (!variableLineNumMap.containsKey(n.getName()))
        {
            setOfLineNum =   new ArrayList<Integer>();
            setOfLineNum.add(n.getBeginLine());
            variableLineNumMap.put(n.getName(), setOfLineNum);
        }
        else
        {
            setOfLineNum = variableLineNumMap.get(n.getName());
            setOfLineNum.add(n.getBeginLine());
            variableLineNumMap.put(n.getName(), setOfLineNum);

        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate the class --->

```
CatchNameExpr nameExp = new CatchNameExpr(classVariables);
        nameExp.visit(classCompilationUnit, null);
```

In a similar manner you can visit the AST for the following expressions, statements, condition etc

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/code/javaparser/javaparser/1.0.8/javaparser-1.0.8-javadoc.jar!/japa/parser/ast/visitor/VoidVisitorAdapter.html

I am well aware that  byte-code processor will be more efficient, and will do the job better than i can hope for. But given the time limit, this option fitted me the best.

Thanks guys,
Jasmeet

Comment: Now that you worked with it, can you tell me if you have access to a the type of an `Expression`, somehow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851648/

Answer (score 2):

To do the task of finding usages of variables, a parser buld with ANTLR should also produce AST. I am almost sure you can find ready AST builder, but don't know where.

Another approach is to analyze class files with [ASM](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFQQFjAD&url=http://asm.ow2.org/&ei=WPmyUMyjEO2Q4gThvoGYCg&usg=AFQjCNEv2IRP-KCv_PInxMBDtMibNLnWlw&sig2=VgVRVVJHuOW9xduWAIA8sg), [BCEL](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CGYQFjAF&url=http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html&ei=WPmyUMyjEO2Q4gThvoGYCg&usg=AFQjCNGqEP9PdX1RAzShft8WdQ48gGLTVw&sig2=pcsg9LxhaHBBlIHFSCnDvw) or other class file analyzer. I think it is easier, and would work faster. Besides, it would work for other jvm languages (e.g. Scala).

Answer (score 2):

To ask questions as to whether a variable read is "global" or not, you need what amounts to a full Java compiler front end, that parses code, build symbol tables and related type information.

To the extent the compiler has actually recorded this information in your class files, you may be able to execute "reflection" operations to get your hands it.  To the extent that such information is present in .class files, you can access it with class-file byte-code processor such as those mentioned in Kaigorodov's answer.

ANTLR has a grammar for Java, but I don't believe any support for symbol table construction.
You can't fake this yourself; Java's rules are too complex.   You might be able to extend the ANTLR parser to do this, but it would be a LOT of work; "Java's rules are too complex".

I understand the Java compiler offers some kind of name/type accurate access to its internal structures; you might be able to use that.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has full Java parsers, with name and type resolution, and could be used for this purpose.