# How to replace all String.equals by StringUtils.equals

Tags: java, code-translation

I want to automatically replace all occurrences of

```
if(variable!=null && variable.equals(value)) ...
```

by

```
if(StringUtils.equals(variable, value)) ...
```

in a type-aware manner. That means, that `variable` and `value` should be *sure* to be `String` (not just lexicographical processing, eg. with awk/perl).

Also it should be flexible enough to apply for `value` as literal as well as a constant (`final static`) or another variable or parameter -- anything that is sure to be a `String` in this context. Also, there may be more boolean expressions following.

I suspect that [Java Std API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/) may help here, but the code-transformation itself is not handled by that API, just the access to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using netbeans you can use a custom refactoring:

Menu Refactor/Inspect and Transform/Browse/New/Edit Script:

```
<!description="Convert to StringUtils.equals">

$var!=null && $var.equals($val) :: $var instanceof java.lang.String
=> StringUtils.equals($var, $val)
;;
```

Comment: Nice. If you put `=> org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.` in you also get the import.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ IDEA's Structural Search and Replace feature is able to make such transformations. See the [Web help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [JAPA](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaparser108sourcesjar.htm) known as Java parser. This is best code change tool i used. From reading a single line in if loop till saving it back to same source it has everything. Worth trying.

Comment: Good hint, I tried it. But I have the feeling it is not far with the "type-awareness" of that tool. I am stuck at how to find out if the sides of the binary expression is really a `String`, i.e. `@Override public Node visit(BinaryExpr n, A arg) { Expression left =  (Expression) n.getLeft(); Expression right =  (Expression) n.getRight(); if(n.getOperator() == BinaryExpr.and) { if(left ...) ... /* how to get to the type??? */ return n; } else { /* default behaviour */ ...  }` I don't think *javaparser* is suited for that, or am I missing anything?

Comment: you can identify some pattern use Brute -force way to replace. :)

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean "brute-force"? You mean the perl-ish approach inside javaparser? No, I stick with perl alone in that case.